BCC issues Iron Slab in ase
I've been having issues trying to optimise a 3x3 bcc slab of iron in ase. When modelled as an fcc struture it isn't problematic but given that iron is bcc it's naturally important I have it run as bcc.
Initially convergence issues seemed to be due to something bizarre but upon further inspection if the lattice constant is left as such then the slab is spaced with the individual atoms extremely far apart, and if halved, as is normal, then the atoms are compressed together[![3x3 iron slab][1]][1]
If anyone has any ideas that would be great. Code can be seen :
a = 2.855 * 1.219

# Create a slab of iron (Fe) in the fcc structure
atoms = bcc111(symbol='Fe', size=(3, 3, 3), a=a/2, vacuum=5.0)

# Fix the bottom layer of atoms
constraint = FixAtoms(indices=[atom.index for atom in atoms if atom.tag == 3])
atoms.set_constraint(constraint)

# Randomly displace the atoms to break symmetry and avoid local minima
atoms.rattle()```


  [1]: https://i.sstatic.net/EDHdq0JZ.png


You should just use a = 2.855 instead of a = 2.855 * 1.219. For example, the ASE default lattice constant for bcc Fe is 2.87, see ase.data.refence_states['Fe'].

The problem you observe is due to the BCC(111) surface requiring 3 layers to form one "layer" as you would think of it probably.  As Shaun Han suggested, the lattice constant you are using is far too large.
Here is an example of a 3x3x9 surface of Fe using a correct lattice constant.

from ase.build import bcc111
from ase.visualize import view
from ase.constraints import FixAtoms
from ase.data import reference_states, atomic_numbers
from icecream import ic
from math import ceil

a = 2.855 * 1.219
ref_a = reference_states[atomic_numbers["Fe"]]["a"]

ic(a, ref_a)

a = ref_a # Lets use a proper lattice constant

intended_layers = 3
layers_per_z_unit = 3
total_layers = intended_layers * layers_per_z_unit

# Create a slab of iron (Fe) in the fcc structure
atoms = bcc111(symbol='Fe', size=(3, 3, total_layers), a=a, vacuum=5)

# Fix the bottom layer of atoms
constraint = FixAtoms(indices=[atom.index for atom in atoms if atom.tag > ceil(total_layers / 2)])
atoms.set_constraint(constraint)

# Randomly displace the atoms to break symmetry and avoid local minima
atoms.rattle()
view(atoms)

